# Internet Explorer If statement and $.get ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, google-chrome

I have a some code that works perfectly in chrome, but it goes wrong in IE. The if condition works perfectly in chrome, but it seems like in IE the first condition is always executed regardless of the value of the resData. I wiresharked the response, and the packet contains 'started', but it still goes in the first if condition if(resData==='not runnin').

```
$.get('/getOutputBuffer', function(resData){
    if(resData === 'not running'){
        $('#output').append('Executable not started<br>');
    }
    else{
        $('#output').append('Executable started (Now listening)<br>');
        if(resData !== 'no updates'){
            $('#output').append('status is ' +resData);
        }
    }
});
```

Edit:

I have changed all the if condition with " == " .

After more debugging, it doesn't always execute the first if condition, the ajax function seems to be the problem. It GETs the proper data value the first time it is executed after the page is loaded, but any other GET will give me the first value, even if in wireshark it shows the proper updated value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the infamous IE-AJAX caching problem. Here's some info http://ajaxian.com/archives/ajax-ie-caching-issue but Google will probably provide you with some more. IE caches the responses, so I guess that's why you're getting the first response again and again. I'm a little bit confused because you see in Wireshark that the requests are being made, but try setting the URL to something like `'/getOutputBuffer?r=' + new Date().getTime()` and see what happens.

Comment: Exactly the problem. Changed my $.get for $.post and changed my get requests server side for post and it all works. The reason is that post does not cache after every request unlike get, just like accordingly to specification. Funny that chrome doesnt follow this, but IE does.

Answer (score 3):

Do not use "===", just use "==". There is a type difference between a string OBJECT and a string LITERAL. In this case, you only care about value equivalence, not (value + type) equivalence.

Comment: Tried it, it doesnt fix the problem. I did edit my post, it seems to related to something else the if condition.